# Gnuplot - Multiple "xtic" parameters

Tags: gnuplot

[Current Plots - need to combine them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1vPe.png)

My data looks like 
0.9000000000000000 -0.572163 -118.847449 -28.339693 -57.091368 -28.256491 
0.9010000000000000 -0.574697 -119.339844 -28.271377 -57.478850 -28.158812 
0.9020000000000000 -0.581214 -119.884476 -28.207152 -58.066133 -28.084056 
0.9030000000000000 -0.576983 -120.334988 -28.125961 -58.626419 -28.007351 
0.9040000000000000 -0.585352 -120.814916 -28.030456 -59.158599 -27.913946 
0.9050000000000000 -0.582894 -121.399251 -27.945236 -59.732370 -27.832271 
0.9060000000000000 -0.588467 -121.874480 -27.879678 -60.276944 -27.746891 
0.9070000000000000 -0.587192 -122.408344 -27.783382 -60.778178 -27.665076 
0.9080000000000000 -0.592806 -122.988079 -27.696940 -61.382354 -27.568282

I am able to graph the data how i want; however i cannot seem to get the X-Axis to cooperate. The script is shown below...

set xlabel "Frequency"
set ylabel "S21 - dB"
set y2label "S11 - dB"
set y2range [-50:0]
set yrange [-100:0]
set ytics 10
set y2tics 5
set grid
set xtics rotate

plot "gnu.dat" every ::15 using 2:xtic((int($0) % 5)==0?stringcolumn(1):"") with lines axes x2y2, \
'' every ::15 using 4 with lines axes x1y1

When i go to plot "...2:xtic..." it only allows for 1 parameter to be fed into the xtic function. Is there any way to pass 2 arguments into the "xtic" function? i have made multiple attempts to xtic(blah blah) and i have tried to cascade them xtic(blah):xtic(blah), but it sends an error or only displays the last arugment passed.

From the image attached i want to be able to combine the X-axis from both images into one. Is this possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand your comment about 2 arguments to xtic(). Also it is not clear whether you are expecting the x coordinate to be generated from column 1 (in which case you need to add that to the using specifier) or from the line number (column 0). But the answer to generating both regularly spaced tics and data-dependent tics is to use the "add" keyword:

```
set xtics add .1         # regularly spaced tic mark every 0.1
plot ... using 1:2:xticlabel((int($0) % 5)==0?stringcolumn(1):"")
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, To clarify i want the x-coordinate to stem from column 0, so from the data above x coordinate is far left, while i base my y-axis coordinates from any column i choose on the right
0.9030000000000000 -0.576983 -120.334988 -28.125961 -58.626419 -28.007351

Answer (score 0):

I am terribly sorry for asking this question poorly, I was able to achieve exactly what i desired by using

stats "file" every using 1
set xrange[STATS_min:STATS_max]

I also used Ethans "ADD" function to help with the rest of the script.